# SQL query for counting sets of values

Tags: sql

Added more information to clear up some confusions. Thanks.

I am trying to group sets of values in SQL. I have the following table and trying to somehow get the results as shown in the following table. I have explored group sets in SQL 2008, cubes, basic group by clauses, but I am not able to figure out the SQL query. Can someone please help. You can change the end resultant table format if you want but the basic idea is about how to count similar sets of values. In this table a,b,c exists 2 times so the count is 2 and x,y exists 3 times so the count is 3 and x, y, z exists 1 time so the count is 1. Please help.

### UserId    ProductId

1         a
   1         b
   1         c
   2         x
   2         y
   3         x
   3         y
   4         x
   4         y
   5         a
   5         b
   5         c
   6         x
   6         y
   6         z

### ProductId Count

a         2
   b         2
   c         2
   x         3
   y         3
   x         1
   y         1
   z         1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(`ProductId`),`ProductId ` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `ProductId` ORDER BY `ProductId` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductId, COUNT(UserId) AS NbrOfUsers
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ProductId, COUNT(UserId)
```

You're selecting `ProductId` & the count of how many `UserId` exist for that `ProductId`.
`GROUP BY ProductId` will group your counted `UserId` based on `ProductId` and also display the count as `NbrOfUsers`.

Your output will look like this:

ProductId    NbrOfUsers
a            2
b            2
c            2
x            3
y            3

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, your query returns number of users each product has. If there was one more row in the original table 1 d then your query returns one more row d 1 in your resultant table. But what I want is the count of the sets.